# How to publish Domain Events in axon framework

Tags: axon

In saga, I wanna publish domain events. but to instantiate DomainEventMessage, I need to put sequenceNumber but I have no idea how to obtain or generate it correctly.

```
public GenericDomainEventMessage(String type, String aggregateIdentifier, long sequenceNumber, T payload) {
    this(type, aggregateIdentifier, sequenceNumber, payload, MetaData.emptyInstance());
}
```

Now what I do is dispatching dommand instead and let's axon handle it.
But problem now is I got tons of useless command class and command handling.
I wanna know how to publish domain events directly or a proper way to create DomainEventMessage

Comment: https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/510

problem solved !!